# Organizing html structure with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

- Header: fixed at top of the screen.
- sideNav: semi-fixed position, scrollable based on its own content size.
- mainDisplay: semi-fixed position, scrollable based on its own content size.
- Footer: fixed at the bottom.

sideNav and mainDisplay side-by-side

semi-fixed: Normally in the screen, it is fixed, but when its content will reach at the end (in case of large scrollable content of sideNav/mainDisplay) then only the footer section will come upwards at the bottom of the screen.

only HTML, CSS, JS are preferable. Possible to implement idea of semi-fixed? any help...

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header,
section,
footer,
aside,
nav,
article,
hgroup {
  display: block;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --navMenuWidth: 100px;
}

#header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6A1B9A;
  color: azure;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

#footer {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #D500F9;
  bottom: 0;
}

#sideNav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  width: var(--navMenuWidth);
  overflow: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: linear-gradient(#ec7014, #081d58);
  float: left;
}

.mainDisplay {
  width: calc(100% - var(--navMenuWidth));
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">This is the header</div>

  <div id="mainBox">
    <nav id="sideNav">
      <ul>
        <li class='menuItem hasSubMenu'>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 1">Item 1</span>
            <span class="subMenuIcon"></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="subMenuList">
            <li class="subMenuItem">
              <a href="http://google.com">Submenu1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">
              <a href="http://google.com">Submenu2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 2">Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button id="iconMenu" class="iconMenu">
            <span class="iconMenuLabel" title='iconMenu'>icon menu</span>
        </button>
    </nav>

    <div id="mainDisplay">
      Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you are facing?

Comment: Not facing error, unable to implement semi-fixed scrolling as described. As seen from snippet, 1. `mainDisplay` is not in-line/side by side, 2. Footer is not positioned as described in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your time. I did it in the following way...

```css
:root {
    --navMenuWidth: 200px;
    --headerHeight: 50px;
}

*{
 margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    display: inline-block;
}

#header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: var(--headerHeight);
    background: rgb(186, 43, 214)
}

#sideNav{
    overflow: auto;
    width: var(--navMenuWidth);
    height: calc(100vh - var(--headerHeight));
    float: left;
}
.menuItem{
    height: 100px;
}

#mainDisplay{
    overflow: auto;
    width: calc(100vw - var(--navMenuWidth));
    height: calc(100vh - var(--headerHeight));
}

#footer{
  background: rgba(66, 212, 74, 0.904);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">This is the header</div>

  <div id="mainBox">
    <nav id="sideNav">
      <ul>
        <li class='menuItem hasSubMenu'>
          <div class="subMenu">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 1">Item 1</span>
            <span class="subMenuIcon"></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="subMenuList">
            <li class="subMenuItem">
              <a href="http://google.com">Submenu1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">
              <a href="http://google.com">Submenu2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 2">Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 2">Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="menuLabel" title="Item 2">Item 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="mainDisplay">
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes made:

1) for footer added

```
position:fixed  //to fix it at bottom
width:100%      //to display div with 100% width
```

2) for mainDisplay:

Removed dynamic width component from side navigation and main display and added position: relative to side nav. so now main display is changed accordingly.

Added fixed width to side nav

**Update :**

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6wbfukj9/25/

**Note: Avoid using calc. it causes calclulations on every mouse movement effectively causing strain on browser.**

Comment: I don't want the footer to be seen at the beginning screen if the content is large.

Comment: @Mr.EU header should be fixed while mainDisplay is scrolling?